# How show Attributes which appear In Many To Many association

Tags: uml, modeling, class-diagram

As we know a many to many association are shown by two asterisks in both end of association. Now I have a association between two entities "Good" and "Invoice" so Good and Invoice have a many to many association but I want to show the "count of each good" in each invoice on class diagram.

How can I show it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an association class as depicted e.g. here: http://www.agilemodeling.com/style/classDiagram.htm

Using a new class and two associations inbetween like user1598390 described is valid as well. It depends how you would like to see the relationship between your entities. UML-wise association classes are probably more concise. Regarding the implementation in a programming language both solutions might even look the same (implemented with an additional link object as most programming languages don't support attributed links or pointers).

Answer (score 2):

Often times many to many associations indicate the need for a third entity.

You need InvoiceDetail entity.

Anyway "count of each good" should be a method in class Invoice.

```
public int getCountOfGood(Good good);
```

there can also be a method that returns a data structure with the count of each distinct Good in the Invoice

```
public Map<Good><Integer> getCountOfEachGood();
```

**Good entity is oblivious of Invoice.**